# How Can I close the service for a specific user in Exchange Server 2007

Tags: exchange-server-2007

I am new to Exhange Server2007 programming. My scenario is to read mails from more than one user account at a time. Now I am reading information of one user but not for the second user at same time. Can an anybody help me to get this. I am assuming that how I can close the service for a specific user and continue for the other user with the same service.

It's a deadline situation. Immediate response can be greately helped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Exchange Web Services or EWS Managed API, you don't need to close anything.

Given the appropiate permissions (this is what you really need), just open the other users mailbox by specifying the users primary email address in the Bind operation:

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("someone@company.local")));
```